# Fork bend issue!

Tags: motorcycle, pulsar, forks

I have a Pulsar 180 2016 model. I recently met with an accident and I replaced the doom and light set everything. Now when I leave hands from handlebar and drive, my ride control is missing and is slightly moving towards the left side. How do I figure out Whether my fork is bent or what else might be wrong? How would I fix it?

Comment: Does your handle shakes back and forth under braking? Please, don't leave hands and drive again.

Answer (score 0):

I would go to a specialist to get the alignment checked, there could be damage that you cannot see with the naked eye. If the bike drifts to the lhs then something is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Something is out of line.. Depending on the accident and impact points,  perhaps first check just to make sure that the wheels & axles haven't been knocked out of alignment. Sometimes after a low speed crash or drop you can realign the forks if they're perhaps slightly twisted but its best to get someone who's got experience with this to do it.

If its more serious impact than a slight knock, you'd be best to have the bike checked for alignment properly. Forks and headstock take quite an impact in accidents and should be tested for damage & alignment with the proper equipment.

Answer (score 0):

If the forks are really bad, you can sometimes see creases where the metal has folded. Bent forks can also be extremely subtle. To check them you need to take them apart and roll them on a flat, clean surface. Any bend will be apparent by a change in the profile between the fork stanchion and surface. This is really the DIY at home method of checking them. Professionals have very delicate and precise instruments for measuring forks.

It's possible to have forks straightened, although it can only be done with very subtle bends, and the cost for doing so is usually about the same as buying a good used set. There is also a risk that the strength of the forks have been compromised while being bent back and forth.

As mentioned in some other answers, I would start with trying to loosen the bolts around the triple tree and wheel and let everything realign. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFV7ZJrORWw

It's also possible this is a problem with the headstock, or some other part of the frame.